# How to solve "object is not defined"

Tags: python

I wanted to randomize math question inside a snake game. And allow the snake to eat it.
Therefore I have to make question appear on the screen.
And the answer and wrong answer has to appear as the food.
How to solve ""answer" is not defined"?

class Question:

```
def question():
    num_1 = random.randint(1,12)
    num_2 = random.randint(1,12)
    
    n = random.randint(1,99)
    answer = num_1 * num_2
    canvas.create_text(window,0,
                     font=('consolas',50), text= "{}x{}=".format(num_1,num_2) , fill="red", tag="question")
```

The food code

class Food:

```
def __init__(self):

    x = random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE)-2) * SPACE_SIZE
    y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / SPACE_SIZE) - 2) * SPACE_SIZE

    self.coordinates = [x, y]

    canvas.create_text(x, y, 
                   font=('consolas',50), text= answer , fill="red", tag="food") # this is [line 47,Col52]
```

Problem : "answer"is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable) [Ln47,Col52]

Comment: please dont post code/error messages as an image, copy it as a text instead. Anyway - it says the problem is on line 47, which is not shown here nor in the screenshot, so it's really difficult to give you any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Answer` is not global. if you want to access it from the other class you either need to declare it as global variable or you need to pass the variable when calling the other class.

You might want to check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) which explains global variables with playground for you to try

Comment: After I've added global the problem solved, but answer seem cannot be defined in food code. May I ask how to solve it too?
NameError: name 'answer' is not defined

Comment: @Kelly, I am glad your problem is solved since this is the case pls accept the answer as correct. Furthermore. Pls declare the `answer` outside of all the classes or functions for it to work properly. You can perhaps add it to the first line of the file

Comment: @Kelly make sure to add `global` before the `answer` before updating the value. Else it will update local value not the globally defined `answer`